# Is there any website showcasing all of the available UI components and widgets with source code?

Tags: java, android, android-widget, ui-guidelines

I was looking for something like the [Visual Guide to Swing Components (Windows Look and Feel)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/compWin.html).

A page that shows the Android UI components.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android documentation has a whole section dedicated to [User Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html) with source code examples. The most important sub-sections are the following:

- [Declaring Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html),
- [Creating Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html),
- [Creating Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

If you haven't check these, you should.

Furthermore, you also have these:

- [Hello, Views](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html)
- [A Visual Guide to Android GUI Widgets](http://www.droiddraw.org/widgetguide.html)
- [Android Development Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html)